# Django and nginx: How to add url prefix to all the django urls

Tags: django, nginx

I have the following nginx config: I am running two servers Nodejs(port:3000) and django(port:8000)

```
http {
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;  <-- NODEJS APP
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; <-- DJANGO APP
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access Django at `{domain_name}/api` and anything other than that will be fetched from Nodejs

I want to access all the `/admin` and whatever urls mentioned in the Django at `/api`

Is there any way to do that.

I know i can add `/api` infornt of all the urls in the `urls.py`.

But this can be dynamic. So I dont want to disturb the urls.

Comment: did you tried the regex ? if not try regex you know that whatever the url from your django app.

Comment: What is serving Django? With Gunicorn you can add `--env SCRIPT_NAME=/api` to the start up command (or set the env another way) and add `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "/api"` to django settings. You'd also need to prepend `/api` to `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL`. With Uvicorn just adding `--root-path="/api"` to start up command could be enough.

Comment: i am using `runserver` currently in that case how to do

Comment: @Santhosh What about `location /api/ { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/; }` (note the trailing slash after the `proxy_pass` directive parameter)?

Comment: @Santhosh  " manage.py runserver"  not support SCRIPT_NAME, https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30634